# How to display a placeholder if nothing is present (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this if/else statement for my rails app. I am trying to display a placeholder for my item list when a user has nothing in their shopping cart.

```
<% if @cart_packs.nil? %>
  < placeholder >
<% else %>
  <% @cart_packs.each do |pack| %>
    < cart item stuff >
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The placeholder is not visible even though there is nothing yet added to the cart. Is there an error in my code? or is there another way to handle this?

If there is a jQuery function to deal with this I will also greatly appreciate that as an alternative, Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When there is nothing in your `@cart_packs`, it is nil, or is it empty array? If the second, try using:

```
<% if @cart_packs.blank? %>
```

Instead of `nil?`. Because empty array is not `nil`, your code always jumps right into `else` statement.

Comment: This works perfectly, I didn't realize that `.blank?` was a method for determining the presence of items in an array, Thanks @Krzysztof!

Comment: @Jake `blank?` is a general purpose method if your receiver's class is uncertain, for example if `@card_packs` could be `nil` or array. If `@card_packs` is guaranteed to be an array, you can use [`Array#empty?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-empty-3F)

Comment: .blank? also works on empty strings. generally should always use .blank? in rails @Jake

Comment: For a simple String, I wanna mention `presence`, It is similar with `present?`, it return the object if it is present, and return `nil` if the object is blank.So to display a default a placeholder, I can do something like this` <%= @name || "placeholder" %>`